# Core dump issue

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I would like to create a C program that retrieves the inode information of a file (or a directory file) and put it as a parameter and display the file creation date but I have a segmentation problem. I don't know how to fix it.
PS: I should use Ctime.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    struct stat *buffer = NULL;
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
    stat (argv[1],buffer);
printf("Date de création du fichier:  %s", ctime(&buffer->st_ctime));
printf("Numéro inode: %ld\n", buffer->st_ino);
return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHvNw.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post pictures of text. Instead copy&paste your error messages, commands, input and output as formatted text directly into your question.

Comment: You do not check of `argv[1]` is valid. If you do not pass any command line arguments, `argc` will be 1 and `argv[1]` will be `NULL`. Most likely not a value, `stat` might like to get passed to it.

Comment: In your picture you are not passing any path, therefore `argv[1]` is `NULL` and you get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

I made a number of changes to the code. I'll detail them below.

```
% cc -o core core.c ; ./core test.txt
Date de création du fichier:  Sun Sep 11 12:03:26 2022
Numéro inode: 41714431
% cat core.c
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    struct stat *buffer = NULL;

    if (argc < 2 || argv[1] == NULL) {
        printf("Need a file name\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("malloc:");
        exit(1);
    }

    int ret = stat (argv[1], buffer);
    if (ret) {
        perror("stat:");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Date de création du fichier:  %s", ctime(&buffer->st_ctime));
    printf("Numéro inode: %llu\n", buffer->st_ino);
    return 0;
}
```

- You should include <time.h> as you are using `ctime()`.
- Checking there is at least one argument (the argc & argv[1] check) is important.
- The memory allocation could fail, so I verify we have memory allocated.
- The `stat()` could also fail, let us verify that is a success.
- I changed the `%ld` to `%llu` to better match `st_ino`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no need to allocate `struct stat` on the heap. Just use a local stack variable

```
struct stat buf;
int err = stat(argc[1], &buf);
```

---

Next, the error comes from the missing declaration for `char *ctime()`.
When the C compiler has no declaration for `ctime()`, it assumes a return type of `int`. Since this doesn't match the format string of `%s`, anything can happen.

---

You can see this, when you add compiler warnings

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra a.c
/tmp/a.c: In function ‘main’:
/tmp/a.c:13:45: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ctime’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   13 | printf("Date de création du fichier:  %s", ctime(&buffer->st_ctime));
      |                                             ^~~~~
/tmp/a.c:13:41: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   13 | printf("Date de création du fichier:  %s", ctime(&buffer->st_ctime));
      |                                        ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                         |   |
      |                                         |   int
      |                                         char *
      |                                        %d
```

You may fix this by declaring `ctime()` through

```
#include <time.h>
```

Now, the program runs without dumping core.